# Convert NSTimeInterval to NSData and back to NSTimeInterval

Tags: swift, nsdata, nstimeinterval

How do I convert an `NSTimeInterval` value to `NSData`?

Comment: why do you need to do that?

Comment: to send to a peer the time i sent an invitation to him to see who sent it first (Multipeer connectivity), i have a problem that when 2 peers send invitations to one another before each of them recieved the invitation the other sent them, so both thinks they are the sender not the receiver.

Comment: so you're hoping both devices times are set correctly so you can compare? send an NSDate that you can easily archive

Comment: so how do i convert NSDate to NSData?

Comment: Posted an answer tested with Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0.  Let me know if you're using a different version of Swift and this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also use [`NSKeyedArchiver`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/index.html):

```
    let time = NSTimeInterval(100)

    let archivedTime = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(time)
    let unarchivedTime = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(archivedTime) as! NSTimeInterval
```

Comment: This isn't the best solution, as `unarchiveObjectWithData` can raise an exception.  But because this method doesn't "throw" its exception, there is no way to catch it with Swift, which can cause your app to crash.

Answer (score 4):

**Xcode 8.3.1 • Swift 3.1**

```
var nowInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970                                  // 1491800604.362141
let data = Data(bytes: &nowInterval, count: MemoryLayout<TimeInterval>.size)    // 8 bytes
let timeInterval: Double = data.withUnsafeBytes{ $0.pointee }

let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval)   // Apr 10, 2017, 2:03 AM"
```

Answer (score 3):

`NSTimeInterval` is just a typealias of `Double`.  You can archive it by copying the bytes like you would with any other Foundation type.

```
var time = NSTimeInterval(100) // 100.0

let timeData = NSData(bytes: &time, length: sizeof(NSTimeInterval))

var unarchivedTime = NSTimeInterval() // You need to initialize an empty NSTimeInterval object as a var in order to mutate it

timeData.getBytes(&unarchivedTime, length: sizeof(NSTimeInterval))

print(unarchivedTime) // 100.0
```

Comment: This does not work with XCode 7.2, etc ... won't accept the "&" and then, after removing, throws an error about casting to an UnsafePointer.

Comment: @DanShev working fine for me in a Swift iOS Playground in Xcode 7.2 http://i.stack.imgur.com/dNhdk.png.  Can you post the full context where you're calling this code?